# OSX/Swift Make Application Useable Anywhere

Tags: swift, macos

I have an application written in osx swift, and I need help with a particular behavior/issue. I have the application set to be above all other windows using this code:

```
self.window!.level =  Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(Int32(kCGScreenSaverWindowLevelKey)))
```

A little issue with it, from what I've seen, is that it does work... but if I go to my launchpad applications menu, the window still shows up. That's exactly how I want the window to behave, but whenever I hit a button within the window, the application resets to the normal desktop to function properly. I have a link below demonstrating this:

https://gyazo.com/f4d05c10ad7b5dbf8b95f3bd2aa23cc4

See how I'm getting taken out of my launchpad and then reset to the normal desktop screen whenever I hit buttons within my application? I just really need to fix this issue.

Is there any info.plist property that I can use to prevent this from happening? Is there any piece of code I could use to make my window use-able everywhere without resetting it to the proper desktop environment? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`NSFloatingWindowLevel`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSFloatingWindowLevel)** might be a better choice:

```
import Cocoa

let kCGFloatingWindowLevel: CGWindowLevel =
    CGWindowLevelForKey(CGWindowLevelKey.FloatingWindowLevelKey)

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        self.window!.level =  Int(kCGFloatingWindowLevel)
    }
}
```

The window level type you are currently using is primarily meant for screensaver windows. If you want a floating palette or window then using the above should give you the desired behavior.

↳ [NSWindow : NSFloatingWindowLevel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSFloatingWindowLevel)

Comment: This might be an extremely dumb question... but how would you declare that?

Comment: I tried using self.window!.level = NSFloatingWindowLevel but that got me a ton of errors D:

Comment: Hmmm... what were the errors exactly? It might help to know that info...

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFloatingWindowLevel' is what I'm getting

Comment: Haha ur gonna hate me for this

Comment: /Users/manishsingh/Desktop/LoLStats/LoLStats/AppDelegate.swift:23:76: 'CGWindowLevelKey.Type' does not have a member named 'FloatingWindowLevelKey'

Comment: It should work if you first declare the function in a `public` method. You might want to show more of your code, or how you've declared it. I just used the exact code above in a new project and it works. Are you using Swift 2.3, or 3?

Comment: Okay so I did declare the public function... but the error is different now (see the older edited message)

Comment: /Users/manishsingh/Desktop/LoLStats/LoLStats/AppDelegate.swift:23:5: Declaring a public let for an internal class

Comment: You should need `public` in the declaration; you can also put the let statement in your class... it should work either way (inside the class or outside of it).

Comment: Alrighty hopefully that should give you all the files!

Comment: It might be better off for you to see the things on your mac just to see

Comment: I just downloaded your code and I converted it to Swift 2.3 syntax and it works. I think you'll want to do that as well...

Comment: I'm on version 6.2

Comment: That's an old version of Xcode! you really need to update... That's part of the problem here I think.

Comment: I also tried to build the code you sent back... but that didn't work

Comment: Any reason you are using such an old version of Xcode?

Comment: I guess I'll update it and let you know what happens ;P

Comment: thx for all the help btw... hopefully the update resolves the problem lol

Comment: Ok so here's what's going on atm! The app does build after updating to the latest version of xcode ;D... But here's the issue. If you remember earlier... the app was still displaying in the launchpad screen, but now it doesn't show up at all. The thing is, I want it to show up there, but instead of it resetting me to my desktop, I need the buttons to still be functional in the launchpad. If you say in the gif i sent, whenever I tried to hit buttons within my app when I was in the launchpad, they would take the app back to the normal desktop. How would I make this happen?